# How can I add padding around the window buttons in macOS (SwiftUI)?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

Good evening everyone,
I am trying to code my first macOS app with SwiftUI in Xcode. Among other things, I pay a lot of attention to an appropriate design. I prefer padding around the window buttons as seen in this picture (example: finder):

[image: Window buttons with paddin]

But at the moment, there isn't much padding around the window button as seen in this picture:

[image: Window buttons without padding]

Is it possible to change that in SwiftUI? Thanks for every answer!

(Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to use a toolbar
[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But is there a way to hide the toolbar in full screen mode?

Comment: Well you can check if the app is in full screen and remove or add the toolbar accordingly